# VueJS, checkbox can't be checked if clicked

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make a custom checkbox in Vue. I stored the checked state in a variable, and with a function I'm trying to invert this status, calling it on click. But it doesn't work and I can't get why.

If I manually change `checked` to `true`, the checkbox behave correctly showing the custom div i used as a tick.

Here's the code:

```
<template>
    <div
        class="cursor-pointer"
        :class="[
            'flex relative items-center h-full w-full p-2',
            props.isEnabled || `opacity-30`,
            props.checkBoxType === 'reverse-between' ? 'justify-between' : 'justify-start',
            props.direction === 'vertical' ? 'flex-col justify-start gap-2' : 'items-center',
        ]"
    >
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            v-model="checked"
            @click="toggleCheckbox"
            class="absolute order-1 w-8 h-8 opacity-0"
            :class="[
                props.checkBoxType === 'reverse-between' && ' right-0',
                props.checkBoxType === 'standard' ? 'order-0' : 'order-1',
                props.direction === 'vertical' && 'top-0 right-4',
            ]"
            :disabled="!props.isEnabled"
        />
        <div
            :class="[
                'bg-white w-6 h-6 flex flex-shrink-0 justify-center items-center p-1 border-2 border-gray',
                props.checkBoxType === 'standard' && props.direction === 'horizontal' && 'order-0 mr-2',
                props.checkBoxType === 'reverse-between' && props.direction === 'horizontal' && 'order-1 ml-2',
                props.direction === 'vertical' && 'mr-0',
                inputShape === 'square' ? 'rounded' : 'rounded-full',
                !props.isToggled && 'border-1',
            ]"
        >
            <div
                v-if="checked"
                :class="[
                    'bg-gray w-3 h-3',
                    props.inputShape === 'circle' ? 'rounded-full' : 'rounded-sm',
                    !props.isToggled && 'hidden',
                ]"
            ></div>
        </div>
        <div
            :class="[
                'select-none font-base flex justify-center items-center',
                props.checkBoxType === 'standard' ? 'order-1' : 'order-0',
                props.direction === 'vertical' && 'text-center',
            ]"
        >
            <span
                :class="[
                    props.textSize ? `text-${props.textSize}` : 'text-base',
                    props.isToggled ? 'font-bold' : 'font-normal',
                    'text-gray',
                ]"
                >{{ props.label }}</span
            >
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
    import { defineProps, ref } from "vue"

    const checked = ref(false)

    const toggleCheckbox = () => {
        checked.value = !checked.value
    }
```

Comment: Is the native `input` element visible and clickable? Do you click on the `input`element?  I'm asking because there is a class `opacity-0`, and because the component as shown seems to work fine in SFC playground when clicking on `input`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to remove the click event, as v-model handles input change out of the box.